# How is a @Model count subtracted

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How is a @Model count subtracted from another @Model count to display the difference. For example the two counts below. So answer should be 0

```
      `@Model.Where(x=> x.Product != null).Count(x=> x.Product.name)
         Subtract
      @Model.Count(x=> x.Product.name)`
```

Comment: `.Count(x=> x.Product.name)` makes no sense.  And you should need to subtract anyway.

Comment: This is bad practice to do those sorts of calculations in your View, it violates SOC. You are better off doing the calculations in the Controller, then assigning the results to properties in your ViewModel directly. The View should simply display properties in your ViewModel.

Comment: If you give an expression to `Count` it should return true or false and indicates that you're filtering the entity set to just those items where the expression evaluates true. A `Where` clause is superfluous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `-` operator, just like any other C# code.

However, you also need to wrap the entire expression in parentheses to prevent Razor from treating the `-` as markup:

```
@(a - b)
```